# Ruby FTP extremely slow under Windows XP

Tags: windows, ruby, ftp

A couple of weeks ago, I wrote a simple Ruby script to test a couple of FTP commands in a Windows XP environment. Everything worked as expected, and I wasn't even aware of the time taken for the code to run (I'd guess 3-4 seconds at the very most.)

A few days ago, a much more involved Ruby application I'm developing started running very slowly. As I investigated the issue, I isolated the problem to the FTP commands. I've now rerun the original test script, and it takes over two *minutes* to run. Command-line FTP is essentially instantaneous.

No files in the ruby directory structure have been changed. I do not believe any new applications have been installed - certainly no other applications appear to be running.

Can anyone suggest why the following code should run so slowly? Manually timing the intervals between `print` statements suggest the `nlst` and `ls` take about 65 seconds each! The profiler gives a much more plausible total ms/call of 16 for `nlst` and 31 for `ls`.

```
require 'net/ftp'

Net::FTP.open("ip_redacted", "user_redacted", "password_redacted") do |ftp|
    ftp.chdir("dir_redacted")

    files = ftp.nlst
    print "files = #{files.sort!}\n"
    list = ftp.ls
    print "list = #{list}\n"

    file = "filename_redacted"

    size = ftp.size(file)
    print "size = #{size}\n"

end
```

Comment: Are you behind a router?

Comment: That's an interesting question. The two machines are on a local network. A tracert from one to the other shows two hops within that network. tracert indicates that all hops are <1 ms, but the tracert itself takes a minute to return. Note that command-line FTP does not show the same delays as FTP from Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a google search:

http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/112910

Hope this helps.

Comment: Outstanding! I've been struggling with this for days. I wish I could upvote this answer more than once.

Comment: BasicSocket.do_not_reverse_lookup = true

Cheers Bob Vesterman.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found Passive mode increased the speed, eg. `ftp.passive=true`.

Comment: Thanks. Disabling reverse DNS lookup worked for me, but others might try passive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `#sort!` (just `puts "files = #{files}"`) since that can be fairly expensive if there's a bunch of files in the directory.  This would account for the large lag around the `#nlst` and the `#ls`

Comment: Thanks, but it makes very little difference in this case - there are only about a dozen files in the directory. By the profiler, the #sort takes 0.00 ms. I've  stepped (or rather nexted) through the code in the debugger, and it's the #nlst and the #ls that are taking the time.