# FTP ant upload takes longer time

Tags: windows, ant, ftp

I am using FTP task to upload from Windows machine to Linux Ftp using the below code.

```
<ftp server="server" port="${ftp.port}" remotedir="/buildfolder" 
userid="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.passwd}" depends="no" binary="yes" passive="yes">
                <fileset dir="E:/BUILD2/">
                    <include name="**/*.*" />
                </fileset>
            </ftp>
```

I am transferring a 300 MB file and it takes 30 min. At the same time, it takes 30 sec in FileZilla as well as in command prompt.

Someone please help for a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ftp to upload with a Firewall connection always consumes lot of time to transfer.

Instead write a batch file to create the ftp commands and call them in ant target to execute.

Now, the speed is amazing!!!

Answer (score 0):

Run ANT in debug mode and try to establish at what point the delay is occurring.

http://ant.apache.org/problems.html

Are you certain Filezilla is not using an alternative protocol like SFTP? Pure ftp might be subject to network firewall issues. Would be best to compare your ANT build with the command-line ftp client on windows.

Another source of networking woes is DNS + enabling FTP passive mode. Try using the IP address and see if this is faster ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874316/ruby-ftp-extremely-slow-under-windows-xp))

Comment: Yes. My FileZilla uses SFTP to transfer these files to the server and it is fast. I have used the command line to transfer and it also transfers at 30 sec.

Comment: In that case this really sounds like an FTP issue. Have you tried some of the advice offered? using the IP address in case it's a DNS issue? Running in debug mode (to find out where in the code it's delaying)? ... Since you're using an SSH based protocol (SFTP) might be a lot simpler to just switch over ANT as well, see the scp task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html

Comment: Yes.. I have tried all the advice that was provided by you. Tried with ip address also. But, still it is the same. :-(

Comment: I realize it's been 5 years, but it's still incredibly slow and I have the same issue. And I am using the IP address not the DNS name.